# CiviCRM Wordpress Cron not running - DB Error connect failed

Tags: wordpress, cron, cli

I've installed CiviCRM in one of my Wordpress site, It installed fine but it is showing me popup window that "No Cron is running", i've tried to setup Cron from my Cpanel with PHP-CLi method, I use this command:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/thetia/public_html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/bin/cli.php  -s thetia.com.au -u database_user -p database_user_password -e Job -a execute
```

When cron executes it send me Email with following error:

Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.

```
DB Error: connect failed
```

I'm providing right username and password but even then it is showing me this error, i don't know what am i doing wrong, any help will be very appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

The reference for cli is [Manage Scheduled Jobs](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs#ManagingScheduledJobs-PHPclimethod). It tells

> This method requires a valid Username and Password (for a Drupal, Joomla or **WordPress** user who has adequate permissions for the job or jobs being run).

So try to run it with a Wordpress user and password.

Comment: You mean i use username and password that i used for Wp-admin?

Comment: Try it. If it it works you can create a seperate WP user that has just enough priviliges to run the cron.